# Intellij IDEA go to previous method shortcut

Tags: java, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

Do you know if IDEA has a shortcut which will bring me to the last method I was looking into, not necessary changing it, just looking into. I know that there is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left/Right</kbd> but it is slightly different.

Comment: Can you explain what's wrong with Ctrl+Alt+left/right. For me it is doing exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a Mac, press <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>.
If you are on a Windows, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>.

This will bring up a searchable list of ALL of the possible shortcuts. Just type what you want to do and it'll come up there. Very handy. I use it all the time.

Hope that helps. Good luck :)

#### EDIT:

Just took a look myself. Doesn't look like there is anything like what you wanted. The closest thing is moving to the the next method or the previous method, but this is just in order of how you have them written in the code, not in the order that you look at them. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean navigate back/forward. You will find it in Settings > Keymap: Main Menu > Navigate > Back

[image: Keymap]